# Linux - restore files from a merged partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ext4, file-recovery

Kind of embarrassing, 
I had a Linux ext4 partition `/dev/sda6`, which was running KDE and I wanted to switch to Ubuntu, so I created a new partition `/dev/sda7` and merged it with `/dev/sda6` so that I can use the space from the original partition.

Little did I know that some code I had written was not pushed to the git repository (rookie mistake), so I'd appreciate any help - all I need to do is restore files from a specific directory - `~/Code/` (or even `~/Code/.git/`). The user in both OS's is named the same, if that matters for the home directory path.

I tried using `testdisk` and `extundelete`, but have come up empty. I'm pretty new to Linux, so I may be using them wrong.